# Extract fields from object to match class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Hey I am having an object like :

```
let o = {"foo":"blah", "blah": "foo", "foo2":"blah2"}
```

and my class is defined as followed :

```
class Foo {
 constructor(public foo: string, blah: string) {}
}
```

is there a way to instantiate foo based on o, by extracting the fields `foo` and `blah` (but not `foo2`). I mean, I know I could write functions to do so, but I was wondering if it was feasible "automatically" ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is something like this:

```
type FooBlah = { foo: string, blah: string }

let o = { "foo": "blah", "blah": "foo", "foo2": "blah2" } as FooBlah

class Foo {
  private foo: string
  constructor({foo, blah}: FooBlah) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

We are [destructuring](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/destructuring.html) the object, then using its individual fields, which keep their type information because of the `FooBlah` type declaration .